# How can i edit my If statement to cater for varying values when working out sales commission

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

At the company I work for, we have sales people who get commission for making sales and this is paid quarterly. How it works is that a sales rep is assigned multiple accounts, and they will earn 0.5% of the first £100,000 that an account spends in a financial year, and then 0.25% of anything on top of that.

So, if an account spends £40,000 in quarter 1, then the sales rep will get £200 if this since that is 0.5% of £40,000. However, if the same account spends £40,000 in the first quarter, £40,000 in the second quarter and then £30,000 in the third quarter - then they will earn another £200 for quarter 2, but only £125 for quarter 3 since £30,000 added to quarters 1 and 2 is £110,000, meaning that £20,000 of the £30,000 will be paid at a rate of 0.5% and £10,000 at a rate of 0.25%.

Its quite a complicated structure as a sales rep's commission relies on how much they earned in the quarters before.

The issue I have is trying to translate this into an Excel formula.

I have attached an image of some account spends and what the commission should be for these accounts per quarter:

[image]

The main issue lies in the commission for quarter 3. The formula I am currently using for cell D3 is `=IF(B2+C2+D2<=100000,D2*0.005,(B2+C2+D2-100000)*0.0025 + (100000-(B2+C2))*0.005)` - which returns the right value, however, when this formula is copied over into cell D5, this returns the value -£354.10. This is most likely because the formula fails when it reaches the final step in working out the sum between the total of the previous quarters and then subtracting 100,000.

The question is how can I edit the formula to cater for values in quarter 3 which raise the total above 100,000 when added to the previous two quarters - whilst also catering for values which are already over 100,000 in both quarter 1 or quarter 2.

I am happy to try and elaborate where needed as I am aware this sounds a little confusing - I am only an Excel novice :)

Comment: `Its quite a complicated structure` - not really, this is how literally every tax bracket calculation is performed.

Comment: okay if you know so much about it then show me the formula that returns 67.44 for account 1 and 146.65 for account 2 mr Gserg

Comment: I [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75746147/11683) four minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

Put in B3:

```
=MIN(SUM($B2:B2),100000)*0.5% + MAX(SUM($B2:B2)-100000,0)*0.25% - MAX(SUM($A3:A3),0)
```

Drag to the right.

Comment: okay so what about account 2?

Comment: @j1mc Copy it from B3 to B5 and drag to the right? Or copy B3:D3 to B5:D5 at once?

Comment: thank you, i am fairly new to excel so i appreciate your input. however, when altering the cells in the formula so i can copy this to my actual spreadhseet, its giving a maximimum of £500 for values in quarter 1 with sales such as £115,000

Comment: @j1mc It's not doing that for me. You have 135796 in your example for quarter 1, and the formula returns 589.49.